# How to get class name in python playwright?

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright-python

How to get a Class name using playwright and pyton?

I tried that but without success.
It could also be the color that is contained in the css

```
page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]').Class()
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML you're working with and the expected result? What does color have to do with class name and what does "without success" mean exactly? BTW, hardcoding a bunch of divs like that looks pretty brittle. Surely there's a more robust selector or path you can pick.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]').get_attribute("class")
```

With method `get_attribute` you can get any attribute from your html element.